# computer crashes immediately after boot

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-8.1, hardware-failure, toshiba-laptop

I've had my laptop for three and a half years now; it's a Toshiba Qosmio X75-A7180 with an i7, Nvidia GTX 770M, and two hard drives, one ssd (Windows is installed here) and one hdd.

It's had issues in the past where it would start booting up, and while displaying "Toshiba - leading innovation", it would make a click noise and power off.  I would then try to power it on and within three tries or so it would work.  About a month ago it did the same thing, only now it won't work at all.  Whenever I try to boot into Windows 8.1, it gets to where it displays "Toshiba - leading innovation", and then it crashes.

I've tried looking at the system from a bootable Linux usb, which worked. After mounting the drives, I got an IO error whenever I try to access either of them.  While still in Linux, I noticed the mbr is on the hdd, which appears to be considered the primary disk by the system (my recovery usb treats it as the C drive, when the computer's main Windows install treats it as the D drive).

I have access to command prompt through the recovery usb, but that's it.  I tried initiating a system refresh in case that magically fixed things, but Windows hasn't fully shut down (hiberboot), so it refused.  Either way, it seems like some weird hardware problem to me.  At some point (possibly tomorrow) I'll open it up and see if there are any obvious issues, but I don't really know what I'll be looking for, so any suggestions would be appreciated.

I'd also be curious to know why the mbr is on the hdd.  Is it just because ssds tend to be less reliable?

Comment: did you try to chkdsk any of them yet?

Comment: Yes; nether of them have problems.

Comment: There will be Mbr on both disks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I opened it up and jiggled some stuff.  I didn't see anything obvious, but I'm also not used to hardware, so I didn't go very far.  I put it back together and... after a month of not working it's now working just fine for whatever reason.  I guess it could have been something was loose, but that just doesn't make sense.

tl;dr: magic happened and it fixed itself.